# Why I couldnt find Settings Alert part in TFS 2010 by using the administration console?

Tags: tfs-workitem, tfs-power-tools

I want to set SMTP Server and other setting for Alert Notification in TFS 2010 ,when I want to follow this steps [Configure Email Notifications and Specify the SMTP Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400808.aspx) I couldnt find 'Email Alert Settings' under 'Application Tier' ,I logged on by TFS Administrator,but where is that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the button of the image.

[image]